# Apache's MultiViews options it not working

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx

**System specs**

- Mac OS Sierra
- Brew installed: Apache/2.4.23

When I access localhost/mypage.php => works

When I access localhost/mypage => does not work

**My configuration**

```
# /usr/local/etc/apache/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        Redirect permanent / https://localhost/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/Documents/mywebsite/httpdocs"
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        <Directory "/Users/myuser/Documents/mywebsite/httpdocs">
                Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews -Indexes
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/ssl/localhost.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/ssl/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**My troubleshooting**

In the Options line, I have tried the following:

- Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
- Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

**Yes, I did restart Apache.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, MultiViews relies on the **negotiation module**.

Mac's install Apache with the following module commented out by default!!

```
# LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/mod_negotiation.so
```

I simply uncommented it and reload Apache. Now it works!